# .Net Core 2.1 End of Life means I need to upgrade azure pipeline version?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm upfrading my application from .Net Core 2.1 to .net core 3.1. Do I need to upgrade azure pipeline version from 2.1?

Comment: why dont you upgrade to .net 5? thats the successor to .net core AND .net framework

Comment: Time constraint, some functionality will require more time to upgrade which we don't have at the moment, so we went with 3.1.

Comment: Hmm it shouldn't be much work just changing a few things in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

On pipeline side you need to add this task to be sure that correct dotnet version is used:

```yaml
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.1.402
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

Comment: Would I be able to use azure pipeline version 2.1, while my app is .Net core 3.1 ?

Comment: No. You need to use 3.1

Comment: Ok, and would 2.1 End of life means that all azure pipelines using 2.1 will stop working ? or will just not get the security updates etc...

Comment: It referes just to dotnet core not to the pipeline nor agent itself. However, there is a chance that in the future a new vmImage will not have dotnet core 2.1 and eol for dotnet means that this particular version won't be maintained (no security updated).